# Find birthdays of employees today

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a query in SQL which will tell me whose birthday is today but the date field in the table is a string value like '20101231' I have tried changing the format by using substring to convert it to look like 12/31/2010 but then again it's still a string value and I can't use the where clause.

I have used the following suggested query but it only works if the column set as date field.

```
SELECT NAME, DOB
FROM TABLE
WHERE DAY(DOB) = DAY(GETDATE())
    AND MONTH(DOB) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Comment: Which version of SQL is this? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, something else?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: `'YYYYMMDD'` is the correct string format for dates in sql server. `date` data type would the correct data type though. [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: I strongly recommend writting a script that reads all the DOB values, parses the string values and writes it to a new DATE column so your query would work. There is not much point in keeping dates as strings. AFAIK, there is no good straightforward function to convert the field

Comment: Can you please tell me then how to pull the birthdays that are today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dates are strings in yyyymmdd format, do this:

```
where right(replace( convert(char(10), getDate(), 102), '.', ''), 4) = right(dob, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can basically work. The simplest is using `FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT NAME, DOB
FROM TABLE
WHERE RIGHT(DOB, 4) = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMdd');
```

I should also note that you can speed this up by creating a computed column with an index:

```
alter table t add dob_mmdd as (right(DOB, 4));

create index idx_t_dob_mmdd on t(dob_mmdd, DOB, Name);
```

And then using this in the query:

```
SELECT NAME, DOB
FROM TABLE
WHERE dob_mmdd = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMdd');
```

Comment: Your query works good but unfortunately I cannot alter the table. Thanks for your help.